# Does join presence event will fire in PUBNUB. If user is already subricibe with channel

Tags: pubnub

Suppose same uuid is subscribe() with channels but they got subcribed at different 
time and from different browser

Scenario

Before 10 min using Chrome

subcribe with channel=>channel_1
with uuid=> abcValue

After 5 min using Mozilla

subcribe with channel=>channel_1
with uuid=> abcValue

```
 var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
            publish_key: "demo",
            subscribe_key: "demo",
            uuid:"abcValue"
        });
pubnub.subscribe({
            channel:'channel_1',
            presence:function(value, envelope, source_channel){
        if( value.action ==="join" && value.uuid === 'abcValue' )
         console.log('Join Called')
});
```

Whether Join Called will get logged twice or not?

Answer (score 0):

Browser isn't the factor.

and no, you don't get two presence join notices when you are using the same uuid, 'abcValue' from Chrome and Firefox, only the first browser (Chrome, in this case) registers the event.

Because 'abcValue' never left, and 'abcValue' joining after 'abcValue' is already joined means you wouldn't get another join.

If you assign a uuid at each connection (so each browser has different uuid), you should see two separated join events are called.

Comment: It's also important to note that these are two different instances that are connection and so the `where_now` call of the second instance might show channels that that specific instance/connection/client has not subscribed if the second connection is started before the first connection timesout (so before the 5 minute mark).

Comment: In other words, if the first connection subscribed to ch1 and the second connection subscribed to ch2 (say 30 seconds later), because you used the same UUIDs, a where_now call will bring back ch1 and ch2 but the second instance is only subscribed to ch2. Just a caveat to be aware of and that you should be sure to consider when using UUIDs from different devices/locations.